# How to list data from two tables in FlatList in React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have two Table in Firebase. I am fetching data and storing it in USERS and in CATES states.
Now When I am listing data in **two Separate** FlatList, My both FlatList gives me separate scrolling. But I want only one Scrolling in entire page.
Please help. Thank You

```
{/* **FlatList 1***/}

<View style={{ backgroundColor: '#fff', marginVertical: 10, borderRadius: 6, paddingBottom: 10 }}>
  <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#dc3545', fontSize: 20, marginVertical: 5, marginHorizontal: 10, paddingVertical: 5 }}>Dishes</Text>
  <FlatList
    data={cates}
    numColumns={4}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
      <TouchableOpacity style={{justifyContent:'center',alignSelf:'center',alignItems:'center',paddingVertical:5,}}>
      <Image source={{ uri: item.catIcon }} style={styles.dishBanner} />
      <Text
        style={styles.dishText}
      >{item.catName}</Text></TouchableOpacity>
    )}
  />
</View>

{/* **FlatList 2** */}
<View style={{flex:1 }}>
  <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#dc3545', fontSize: 20, marginVertical: 5, marginHorizontal: 10, paddingVertical: 5 }}>Restaurants</Text>
  <FlatList
    data={users}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
      <TouchableOpacity style={{backgroundColor: '#fff', borderRadius: 6, paddingBottom: 10, paddingTop: 10,marginBottom:10}}>
      <Image source={{ uri: item.RImage }} style={styles.resBanner} />
      <Text
        style={{ fontSize: 20, fontWeight: '500', textAlign: 'center', color: '#333', }}
      >{item.RName}</Text></TouchableOpacity>
    )}
  />
</View>
```

Comment: I think firebase / google cloud tags should not be used here. This is more a react / css related problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine the two lists to make another that would be displayed a single FlatList with only one render item prop.
If the data represents different aspects of the same items, you will need to look at [SectionLists](https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist)

```js
        <SectionList
          sections={DATA}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item} />}
          renderSectionHeader={({ section: { title } }) => (
            <Text style={styles.header}>{title}</Text>
          )}
        />
```